# Copy and Paste Excel Macro for only rows with data

Tags: vba, excel

I need help in figuring out a macro to copy and paste only values from rows that contain data (and not a large set range) to another worksheet.

The worksheet named `DataEntry` is where downtime is entered in columns A - J (could have 2 rows of data or could have 50) and pastes only the values (and not formulas) into another worksheet named `DataCombined` to column A and on the next available row.

Please help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your question is kind of confusing, but this may be where you want to start:
(If you could please give an example sheet with your desired output, that would help)

```
Sub copyRange()
    Dim dataSht As Worksheet, comboSht As Worksheet
    Set dataSht = Sheets("DataEntry")
    Set comboSht = Sheets("DataCombined")

    Dim rngToCopy As Range

    Set rngToCopy = dataSht.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(getLastFilledRow(dataSht), "J"))
    rngToCopy.Copy
    comboSht.Range("A" & (getLastFilledRow(comboSht) + 1)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    rngToCopy = dataSht.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(getLastFilledRow(dataSht), "J")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    rngToCopy.ClearContents
End Sub

'Gets the last row of the worksheet that contains data
Public Function getLastFilledRow(sh As Worksheet) As Integer
    On Error Resume Next
    getLastFilledRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            LookAt:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Comment: I have data on the DataEntry spreadsheet in rows A2:J8 that needs to be copied and paste special values to DataCombined spreadsheet row A2:J8.  Then I want to clear out the data on the DataEntry Spreadsheet rows A2:J8 and enter more data in A2:j6 and have that submit to the DataCombined spreadsheet to the next available row.

Comment: Ok that makes more sense. I'll modify the code above to reflect that. Is there already a value in cell A1 on the DataCombined sheet?

Comment: there are just headers on A1-J1

Comment: Ok try the above macro now. It will clear out A2:J8 on your dataEntry worksheet after copying over. Please make a backup of your workbook (always) before running new macros on it

Comment: It works!  Just one minor issue, is there a way that it won't clear out column F and I?  There are formulas in there, that it is clearing out.

Comment: Great, you're welcome! Can you please click the "accept my answer" (gray checkmark near the top of the answer, I think) and upvote it since it works?